# iOS UIDatePicker - disable KEYPAD entry

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker displayed with a WHEEL mode, but when I click on a date, the keyboard comes up, letting me enter a date from KEYPAD. How to disable this ridiculous behavior (why would anyone want that anyway???)

Comment: Please update your question with relevant details about your code (as text) or storyboard setup.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's documentation on this is rather lacking -- I haven't been able to find any reference to that functionality.

However, it is clearly built-in as a convenient method for a user to enter the time with the Keypad.

You *can* prevent the Keypad from showing like this:

```
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(noKeypad(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
}
@IBAction func noKeypad(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your method. Even though, it does solve the keyboard problem, it doesn’t trigger a wheel values changes. So, I’m confused.

Comment: @ekashking - not sure what you mean... If I add a target for `.valueChanged` it's called when I change the date/time. Are you expecting `.valueChanged` to be triggered when tapping the time columns?

Comment: I got it. What I did was I added two targets. One is `.editingDidBegin` as you said which prevents the keyboard from showing up. Another one is `.valueChanged` which changes the value on the wheels scroll. It worked just the way I wanted. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.